# Max payne 3 controls

Tags: controllers, max-payne-3

Is there any way to make the controls different where if I look down with the joystick I look down not where I look down and payne looks up

Answer (score 3):

On controls settings, set "Invert Vertical Look" to "Off".

[image]
*Image courtesy of supercheats.com*